# Just got another used women's Giant bike. This is a Sedona. Any way to tell year, and model?

Tags: identify-this-bike

Just got a another Giant that fits me better. Got an XS.  This bike is an S.  The bike is for rider height of 5'4" to 5'7".  It is a Giant Sedona.   Want to sell this one.  Any idea what year and model?  Bought this used as well.

Regards,

Jeri-Anne[image: sedonabike]

Answer (score 1):

bikepedia.com
bicyclebluebook.com

maybe 2010 plus or minus? "W" is the women's model suffix for Giant

Answer (score 1):

With this type of bike in this price range the exact model does really matter for selling. There many manufacturers making hybrids and a plethora of models. Your target audience is going to care about description ('women's step through hybrid'), frame size, how old it is and condition. They are not looking for an exact brand or model.

If you provide a picture of the the rear gear area someone can probably provide a estimate of age based on the model of derailleur.